Passing attribute of vector layer to algorithm in QGIS Model Designer
I am using QGIS 3.34.9 and I have point data with several properties in the attribute table of which one is called "test". I would like to use the "Rectangles, ovals, diamonds" - Tool to draw ovals around each point in the QGIS Model Designer. The width of the ovals should be the value in the attribute table.

It works great outside of the Model Designer, where I can simply call the tool from the processing toolbox and select the field it should read the width from.

Once in Model Designer, the same tool does not find the attribute "test". Here is my setup:


Instead of "test" I have also tried attribute("test") and attribute(test)
All versions result in the following error message:

In addition, I also tried to add the width via a vector field input, however, the drop-down is empty and I cannot select the vector field input there.

How can I pass an attribute from a vector layer to a processing algorithm in the Model Designer?

I can confirm this issue on my QGIS 3.34.8-Prizren

Try 'test' instead of "test".
